# Router.push redirecting but not rendering the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hi I am trying to implement simple route in next js. Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Router from "next/router";

import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";


function Index() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hi Guys!! Welcome!!!</h1>
      <h3>Select your role:</h3>
      <div onClick={() => Router.replace("/admin")}>
        Admin
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

Now when i click the admin page, it redirects it to admin page but does not renders the component. i have to press enter on the component to render it

here is my admin component:

```
import React from 'react';

function Admin(){


    return <h1>Welcome to admin Dashboard</h1>
}

export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure but you can try to use `useRouter` instead

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();
onClick={() => router.push("/admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Router.replace("path to js file", "/admin")
```

Comment: mistake. retry `Router.replace(href, as)`

href - The path inside pages directory. This is the only required prop
as - The path that will be rendered in the browser URL bar. Used for dynamic routes